# SpringBoot Internationalization and Localization based in URL mapping

Tags: spring-boot, localization, internationalization

I'm implementing internationalization and localization in my project where Locale is based in URL mapping of languages, for example, `/en`, `/ja` and `/fr`.
I spend the whole day browsing for answer but majority I read is using `LocaleChangeInterceptor` setter method `setParamName("lang")`. Basically changing Locale upon intercepting parameter lang:

```
http://localhost:8081/index?lang=fr
```

I want to make Locale change based in URL mapping like `http://localhost:8081/index/en`

Current configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.JAPAN);
        slr.setLocaleAttributeName("session.current.locale");
        slr.setTimeZoneAttributeName("session.current.timezone");
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("language/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Resources:

[image]

Comment: Write your own interceptor that understands the URL. Or use a UrlRewriting filter to move the URL part to a parameter so that internally it still works with a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm now answering my question. Thanks to M. Deinum.

First I wrote my own interceptor to scan URL pattern before sending to controller:

```
@Component
public class UrlLocaleInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        String[] tokens = request.getRequestURI().trim().split("/");

        try {
            String newLocale = tokens[1];

            if (newLocale != null) {
                LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);

                if (localeResolver == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("No LocaleResolver found: not in a DispatcherServlet request?");
                }

                if (Languages.getNames().contains(newLocale)) {
                    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, parseLocaleValue(newLocale));
                } else {
                    localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, parseLocaleValue("ja"));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Nullable
    protected Locale parseLocaleValue(String localeValue) {
        return StringUtils.parseLocale(localeValue);
    }
}
```

Second. Initialize `UrlLocaleInterceptor` instance by constructor injection then register it to `InterceptorRegistry`:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final UrlLocaleInterceptor urlInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public MessageConfig(UrlLocaleInterceptor urlInterceptor) {
        this.urlInterceptor = urlInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ja"));
        slr.setLocaleAttributeName("session.current.locale");
        slr.setTimeZoneAttributeName("session.current.timezone");
        return slr;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(urlInterceptor);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("language/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }
}
```

Third. I define `Language` enum to enumerate supported languages by the application. Method `getNames()` is called by `preHandle()` from `UrlLocaleInterceptor`.

```
public enum Languages {
    en, ja;

    public static Set<String> getNames() {
        return Arrays.stream(Languages.values())
                .map(Enum::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

Fourth. I add a path variable `{lang}` to the controller.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{lang}")
public class CustomerController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```